# Calculate previous month value for a current month in snowflak

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I need to calculate Previous Month value for a current month in snowflake. For Example if this is the table

| ID | Current_Month | Current_Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 4 | 5678 |
| 10 | 5 | 1234 |
| 10 | 6 | 9876 |

Now I want like this

| ID | Previous_Month | Current_month | Previous_month_value | current_month_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 4 | 5 | 5678 | 1234 |
| 10 | 5 | 6 | 1234 | 9876 |

I want to have the `previous_month` and `previous_month_value` for the same ID.

Comment: Do a self join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the window function `lag()` applied on data grouped by id :

```
 with cte as (
  select id,
         lag(Current_Month) over (partition by id order by Current_Month asc) as Previous_Month, 
         Current_Month,
         lag(Current_Value) over (partition by id order by Current_Month asc) as Previous_month_value, 
         Current_Value as current_month_Value
  from test_table_mv
  where id = 10
)
select *
from cte
where Previous_Month is not null
```

Result :

| ID | PREVIOUS_MONTH | CURRENT_MONTH | PREVIOUS_MONTH_VALUE | CURRENT_MONTH_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 4 | 5 | 5678 | 1234 |
| 10 | 5 | 6 | 1234 | 9876 |

Comment: What will be the record for current_month = 4. How will that data be shown?

Comment: If you remove the condition `Previous_Month is not null` you will get also result of `current_month = 4` with nulls values on `Previous_Month` and `Previous_month_value`

Comment: When I do that.. the previous row current_month_value is picked and shown in the next row previous_month_value as I have 100+ rows data..

Comment: I couldn't understand! , Could you please edit your question and provide more details, as well as a simple that you are having trouble with?

Comment: When I try to take the code and apply the same with my table columns.. It works fine when I search for a particular ID.. But I have 100's of ID's so when I use your code.. what it does is it takes the previous row **current_month_value** and shows in the next row as **previous_month_value** irrespective of the ID..

So.. to simplify.. for an ID 10 if the **current_month_value** is 20.. and the next record is with an ID 20 the **previous_month_value** becomes the **current_month_value** of ID 10 which is incorrect.

Comment: Lag function takes the previous row to calculate.. but my ask is for a Particular ID.. it can have various month and values.. so for that particular ID.. we need the calculate the previous month and previous_month_value..

Comment: Updated my answer, can you have a look

Comment: What if I want to create a table out of this logic.. ID has to be applied across all ID's and nothing in specific.

Comment: This is beyond the scope of this question; please ask another question, and you will find someone to assist you.

Comment: The previous_month_value calculation is what I want to calculate but that logic should be applied across all ID's.

Comment: Updated my answer, can you check